# empathy client won't launch since upgrade, no command line output

Tags: 14.04, empathy, telepathy

I am having trouble with any chat client (empathy, pidgin) since updating to Ubuntu 14.04. I am thinking for different reasons (pidgin refuses to connect to google talk, empathy doesn't launch)

If I click on empathy, or type it into the command line then nothing happens. Running which empathy produces a correct location.

I have tried purging and reinstalling a number of times. I'm not sure if telepathy is installed properly, as the telepathy repos that were left over from 12.04 gave me a 404 for a trusty release, so I removed them from the source list. I tried to see if telepathy-core is installed and apparently it is not...however this might be useless information because I can not find any new information about telepathy for 14.04.

When empathy installs it brings plenty of telepathy packages with it, so I am assuming that that would at least cause dependency errors in terminal if it wasn't working on launch and install.

Anyway, I can't get any information from the command line as when I call empathy nothing happens. It doesn't hang, it doesn't launch anything. Same if I click in the notification bar and also in the Applications menu

How can I debug this? Is there a way to find out if it is even trying to launch?

Edit:

I managed to get some gdb output of this

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffdef49700 (LWP 6621)]
[New Thread 0x7fffde748700 (LWP 6622)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdd654700 (LWP 6623)]
[Thread 0x7fffdd654700 (LWP 6623) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffde748700 (LWP 6622) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffdef49700 (LWP 6621) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 6617) exited with code 0377]
```

Comment: Yikes, same problem here after updating from 12.04 (although it took a while to manifest). Nothing printed out and very hard to debug.